# Move item in list based on Order property (int) and sort

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I have a list of items where one of the properties is an Order number (int).
I want to find an efficient way to move an item to a desired order number and re-order/sort the list (each number should have a unique order number).

For example, using the list below, I may want to move Jane to be order "1" and move the rest up a number.

```
[
   { order: 1, name: "Bob" }
   { order: 2, name: "Lisa" },
   { order: 3, name: "John" },
   { order: 4, name: "Jane" }
]
```

My current solution involves using 3 methods.
MoveItemUp(), MoveItemDown(), MoveItem()

MoveItemUp() and MoveItemDown() will simply move an item up or down swapping order numbers with its neighouring item.

MoveItem() will check if the desired new order number is greater or lesser than current order, and in a while loop, I will run MoveItemUp() or MoveItemDown() until the item hits its desired new order number.

It works, but can be pretty slow. See code below:

```
private void MoveItemUp(ItemVM item)
{
    if (item.Order <= 1)
        return;

    var itemToMoveUp = items.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == item.Name && f.Order == item.Order);
    var itemToMoveDown = items.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Order == item.Order - 1);

    itemToMoveUp.Order -= 1;
    itemToMoveDown.Order += 1;
    items = items.OrderBy(o => o.Order).ToList();

}

private void MoveItemDown(ItemVM item)
{
    if (item.Order > items.Count())
        return;

    var itemToMoveUp = items.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == item.Name && f.Order == item.Order);
    var itemToMoveDown = items.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Order == item.Order + 1);

    itemToMoveUp.Order += 1;
    itemToMoveDown.Order -= 1;
    items = items.OrderBy(o => o.Order).ToList();

}

private void MoveItem(ItemVM item, int moveTo)
{
    if (item.Order > moveTo && moveTo != 0)
    {
        while (item.Order > moveTo)
        {
            MoveQuestionUp(item);
        }

    }
    else if (item.Order < moveTo && moveTo != 0)
    {
        while (item.Order < moveTo)
        {
            MoveQuestionDown(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a *float* instead of an *int*? Except for a rare need to rebalance, you can always find a new number between any pair of existing ones by taking their average, so can use that to move rows into new positions and *not* have to renumber any other rows. (And also, of course, there's no need to be averse to 0 or negative values either, as you currently seem to be)

Comment: _"It works, but can be pretty slow."_ -  how slow? One thing you can do without improving the algorithmic complexity is to use in-place list sorting with something like `items.Sort((i, i1) => i.Order.CompareTo(i1.Order))`

Comment: Do you always have continuous order numbers starting from 1?

Answer (score 0):

`MoveItemUp/Down` has complexity of `O(n log n)` which makes the `MoveItem` to be `O(n^2 log n)` (and a lot of allocations due to constant `ToList`s). I would consider changing the approach to basically you have defined yourself in the post - *"I may want to move Jane to be order "1" and move the rest up a number."*. Basically move up/down is either just +1 on the order number or swap so it can be implemented something like (since you know that data is already sorted, not tested):

```cs
private void MoveItemUp(ItemVM item)
{
    if (item.Order <= 1)
        return;
        
    var indexToMoveUp = items.FindIndex(f => f.Order == item.Order); 
    var indexToMoveDown = items.FindIndex(f => f.Order == item.Order - 1);

    if (indexToMoveUp < 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("NotFound");
    }

    if (indexToMoveDown < 0)
    {
        items[indexToMoveUp].Order -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        var toMoveDown = items[indexToMoveDown];
        var toMoveUp = items[indexToMoveUp];
        items[indexToMoveDown] = toMoveUp;
        items[indexToMoveUp] = toMoveDown;
    }
}
```

And similar for `MoveItemDown`, which will make them `O(n)`.

As for `MoveItem` you can implement it something like:

```
private void MoveItem(ItemVM item, int moveTo)
{ 
    var indexToMove = items.FindIndex(f => f.Order == item.Order);
    var movingItem = items[indexToMove];
    if (item.Order < moveTo)
    {
        for (int i = indexToMove; i < items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var next = items[i + 1];
            if (next.Order > moveTo)
            {
                break;
            }

            movingItem.Order = next.Order;
            next.Order -= 1;
            items[i] = next;
            items[i + 1] = movingItem;
        }
    }
        
    // similar for the other direction
}
```

Alternative approaches:

1. Use [`SortedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-7.0) which has `O(log n)` insertion and removal (the `MoveItem` though needs to be reimplemented with complete resorting)
2. Maintaining `Dictionary<int, int>` to store the order -> index map, which will make the corresponding `MoveUp/Down` `O(1)` making your current `MoveItem` implementation efficient.
3. If indexes are continuous and always start from 1 (which seems to be the case) then just use list indexer (`items[item.Order - 1]`), but check that the property is maintained. This will make `MoveUp/Down` effectively `O(1)` making your current `MoveItem` implementation efficient.